# How to update Oracle JDK on Debian

Tags: debian, java, jdk

I am planning to install the `oracle JDK7` on my `Debian Wheezy` machine. 
To do so I am using `java-package` to install the `jdk` as a `.deb` package under Debian, as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage).

My question is: Can anybody describe the procedure to update the jdk when installed this way?
Is it simply to repeat the installation steps with a newer jdk binary? Do I need to remove the old one?

Answer (score 1):

you should just be able to repeat the steps, yes, and the files installed by the old `.deb` will be replaced by the new `.deb` (assuming the `.deb` has been created properly).

as a relevant aside, however, you might consider using the repository [described here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html).  i've been using it for a while now with great success.  it's much easier this way!